# does interactive php have something similar to the ~/.irbrc file?

Tags: php, command-line, interactive

I wonder if the

```
  $ php -a
```

have something similar to ruby's ~/.irbrc file.

basically I want to `require 'bootstrap.php';` automatically when I start php -a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future references:

I solved this by using http://phpsh.org/

and using an alias of

alias myphpsh='phpsh bootstrap.php'

Answer (score 2):

From: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php

> **Note:**
>
> Files included through [auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) and [auto_append_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file)
>   are parsed in this mode but with some
>   restrictions - e.g. functions have to
>   be defined before called.

Comment: yes of course i did. (it's the -c option)
the documentation states that autoloading does not work, but it does if I do php -a and then require my bootstrap file. HOWEVER autoloading doesn't seem to work properly when I use the auto_prepend_file solution.

I'll investigate this further but I really need to get some work done now ;)

Comment: Just making sure. It happens all too often that people edit Apache's php.ini and are surprised they don't see changes in CLI

Comment: I never managed to sort this out, as far as I can tell, it's not possible to do what I'm after.